# Meaning of st_ino

Tags: filesystems, inode, stat

This might be an easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere: what does the st_ino field of struct stat contain for filesystems that do not use inodes? I'm interested in particular in what happens with FAT32.

Comment: The Linux fat/vfat driver invents the inode numbers as needed (and you could get different results, depending on how you access the files).  For other systems, the answer can be different.

Comment: @thomas dickey: I see, so the inode number is not linked in any way to the file starting cluster. Any idea how to find the latter?

Comment: Maybe the [mshowfat](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html#mshowfat) command, part of mtools, will show you the starting cluster.

Comment: It seems, from this commentary, that you have not actually asked the question whose answer you actually want to know.

Comment: @JdeBP: Actually I did, without much success though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212406/get-starting-cluster-of-file-on-fat32-filesystem-in-python